Expansion of the associated Legendre polynomials $P^m_l(\cos\vartheta)$ for $\vartheta \rightarrow 0$
A simple test with Mathematica indicates that for the associated Legendre polynomials $P^m_l$ the following relation should hold:
$$ \lim_{\vartheta\rightarrow 0} P^m_l(\cos\vartheta) =a_{lm} \vartheta^{|m|}+{\cal O}(\vartheta^{|m|+1}).$$
However, I cannot find an asymptotic expansion like this anywhere. Can the value of the first expansion coefficient $a_{lm}$ be determined explicitly as a function of $l$ and $m$?
Here are the first few values of $a_{lm}$
\begin{array}{r | c | c | c | c |c }
 m\text{\\}l & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\hline
 0 & 1 &1 &1 &1 & 1 \\
 1 & &-1 &-3 &-6 & -10\\
 2 & & & 3&15 &45 \\
 3 & & & & -15 & -105\\
 4 &  & & & & 105
\end{array}
The closest formula I could find, was the trigonometric expanion formula in Abramowitz, Stegun (8.7.1 p. 335). But it is explicitly only valid for $0<\vartheta<\pi$ and it does not yield the values shown inside the table.

In view the Rodrigues formula for the associated Legendre polynomials, one finds
$$a_{nm}=\lim_{\vartheta\rightarrow 0} \vartheta^{-m}P^m_n(\cos\vartheta)= (-1)^m\frac{1}{2^n n!} \lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{\partial ^{m+n}}{\partial x^{m+n}}\left(x^2-1\right)^n.$$
Then use that
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{\partial ^{m+n}}{\partial x^{m+n}}\left(x^2-1\right)^n=\sum _{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j} \frac{(-1)^j (2 n-2 j)! }{(n-2 j-m)!},$$
as follows from the binomial expansion of $(x^2-1)^n$. The sum over $j$ can be evaluated further, I arrive at
$$a_{nm}=\frac{(-1)^m (n+m)!}{2^m m! (n-m)!}.$$

For computing $\frac{\partial ^{m+n}}{\partial x^{m+n}}(x^2-1)^n$ at $x=1$, we may put $x=1+t$, then we look at the $(n+m)$-th derivative of $(t^2+2t)^{n}$ at 0, that is $(n+m)! $ times the coefficient of $t^{n+m}$ in $(t^2+2t)^{n}$, this coefficient is $2^{n-m}{n\choose m}$.

@FedorPetrov ---  neat, much simpler than my roundabout way!

For completeness, here are the slightly modified expressions for $m<0$:
$$a_{lm}={1\over 2^{-m} (-m)!},$$
as well as the corresponding coefficients for the limit of $x\rightarrow -1$ or $\vartheta \rightarrow \pi$ respectively.
$m\ge 0$:
$$a_{lm}= {(-1)^l (l+m)!\over 2^m m! (l-m)!}$$
and $m<0$:
$$a_ {lm} = {(-1)^{l+m}\over 2^{-m} (-m)!}$$
